# Jquery - Highlight Matching Input Fields

Tags: jquery, forms, field, matching

I've got a table that is dynamically created from a database.
There can be anywhere from 1 to xxx rows generated depending on what the user is doing.

Each row has, amongst other fields, a DropDown and Input field. 
When the dropdown field is changed the value is written to the same rows input field.
This works well.

As each row has the same dropdown options I'm trying to check if 2 or more are using the same values.

The dropdowns are similar to this :

```
 <select name="sel[]" id="sel1" class="select" />
        <option></option>
        <option value="123">Option 1-1</option>
        <option value="456">Option 1-2</option>
        <option value="789">Option 1-3</option>
 </select>
```

**example:**

If Row 1 Option 1-1 is selected. This writes 123 in to Row 1's corresponding input field.

If Row 3 selects Option 3-1, then 123 is written to it's input field.

At that point I'd like the background of row3's input field to turn yellow as it matches with another rows input value.

When a different value is selected, if there is no match I'd like the back ground to revert to white.

I hope that makes sense..

The JQuery I'm using is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#frm1').on('change', 'select[name="sel[]"]', function (event) { 
        var data = $(this).val(); var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#new_'+id).val(data); 

    $('.select').not($(this)).each(function (index) {
        var test = $(this).val(); var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (data === test) { 
            $('#new_' + id).css('background-color', '#FFFF80'); 
        } else {
            $('#new_' + id).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); 
        }
    });       
 });
});
```

And theres a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z8j47xkr/)** showing how far I've got with it.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to get this to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8j47xkr/11/)):

```
<body>
<form id="frm1">
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 146px;">
        <select name="sel[]" id="sel1" class="select" />
        <option></option>
        <option value="123">Option 1-1</option>
        <option value="456">Option 1-2</option>
        <option value="789">Option 1-3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1458px;"><input name="new_sel1" id="new_sel1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 146px;">
        <select name="sel[]" id="sel2" class="select" />
        <option></option>
        <option value="123">Option 2-1</option>    
        <option value="456">Option 2-2</option>
        <option value="789">Option 2-3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1458px;"><input name="new_sel2" id="new_sel2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 146px;">
        <select name="sel[]" id="sel3" class="select" />
        <option></option>
        <option value="123">Option 3-1</option>
        <option value="456">Option 3-2</option>
        <option value="789">Option 3-3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1458px;"><input name="new_sel3" id="new_sel3"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#frm1').on('change', 'select[name="sel[]"]', function (event) {  
            var data = $(this).val(); 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#new_'+id).val(data);      
        $("input[name^='new_sel']").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); 

        $("input[name^='new_sel']").each(function(){  
            var currentVal = $(this).val();
            if(currentVal != undefined && currentVal != "" && currentVal != null)
            {
                var inputs = $("input[value="+currentVal+"]")
                if(inputs.length > 1)
                {
                    inputs.each(function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF80');});
                }
            }                        
        });           

    });
})
```

Comment: Just noticed one small issue.
if another input on the same row has the same value eg:123 then it is also highlighted. How can we get it to only highlight 'new_sel*'  fields and not other fields.

I did try changing `inputs.each(function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF80');});` to `$("input[name^='new_sel']").each(function(){$(this).css('background-color', '#FF4040');});` but that didn't help. Thanks

Comment: Changing from `var inputs = $("input[value="+currentVal+"]")` TO var `inputs = $("input[name^='new_sel'][value="+currentVal+"]")` seems to have worked.